# nginx + passenger + rails: do I need to start the rails server or just start nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to have my rails server listen on 2 different ports. One solution proposed to me was to use nginx. I installed nginx with `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module` and added the following to /etc/nginx/conf.d:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       10000;
    server_name  www.myapp.com
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /root/myapp/public;}
```

When I went to www.myapp.com I got a 403 Forbidden error. I figured it was because there were no static html files in /public. I dropped a simple "hello world" html page in there and it loaded correctly. I then proceeded to start my rails app using `passenger start -e production`, which caused it to run in standalone phusion passenger mode on port 3000. I go to myapp.com:3000 and I get the app. However, myapp:80 and myapp:10000 still don't work. I'm confused on how to get my nginx to point to the rails server I'm running. Am I doing this completely wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Nginx starts up with passenger and is the rails server. Passenger is compiled into nginx as a module, and indeed even in standalone mode it is still running via nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Set nginx to forward to my rails server using this https://gist.github.com/jeffrafter/1229497

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx.error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream dev {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
      listen       80;

      # You could put a server_name directive here (or multiple) if
      # you have not setup wildcard DNS for *.dev domains
      # See http://jessedearing.com/nodes/9-setting-up-wildcard-subdomains-on-os-x-10-6

      # If we choose a root, then we can't switch things around easily
      # Using /dev/null means that static assets are served through
      # Rails instead, which for development is okay
      root         /dev/null;

      index        index.html index.htm;

      try_files  $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @dev;

      location @dev {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_pass        http://dev;
      }
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    }            
}
```